# WPF ListViewItem multiple events via AttachedCommandBehaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i am trying to get two events of the ListViewItem passed to my ViewModel with [AttachedCommandBehaviours](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).

This is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="MouseDoubleClickStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <Setter Property="attachedCommandBehavior:CommandBehavior.Event" 
                    Value="MouseDoubleClick" />
        <Setter Property="attachedCommandBehavior:CommandBehavior.Command" 
                    Value="{Binding ElementName=ServerListView, Path=DataContext.ListViewItemDoubleClickedCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="attachedCommandBehavior:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" 
                    Value="{Binding}" />
    </Style>
```

And this is my ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ServerListView" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MouseDoubleClickStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dienstname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Servername" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HostName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="IP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IpAddress}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

In the ViewModel I created a property of type ICommand, that is called when the command is executed:

```
private DelegateCommand _listViewItemDoubleClickedCommand;
    public ICommand ListViewItemDoubleClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _listViewItemDoubleClickedCommand ??
                   (_listViewItemDoubleClickedCommand = new DelegateCommand(item => Connect((DiscoveredServerItem) item)));
        }
    }
```

This is working fine.
As you see I subscribed for the MouseDoubleClick event.

Now I want to subscribe for the MouseDown event in addition.
And that is where the problem starts.

I searched a lot, and it seems that it's not that easy to attach a command to an event of the ListViewItem.
Is there a chance to add a second command in that style?
The AttachedCommandBehavior v2 does support a BindingCollection, but I do not know how I can use that within a style.

Thanks for your help
caldicot

**EDIT:**

Here are some more information.

I want to write the selected item in a text box (triggered with a click).
I cannot directly bind the selected item to the text box, because the user should still be able to write a custom server ip in that text box.

With a double click the client should connect to the server specified in the text box. 
Maybe there is another solution?

I cannot use the SelectionChanged event from the ListView, because when the user selects an item, and then modifies the text box, the selection changed event will not be fired anymore when clicking on the same entry. As there could be only one entry in the ListView there is no chance for the user to re-select this item.

Comment: Why don't you try InputBindings instead of AttachedCommandBehaviour

Comment: Actually I don't know. Is there a way to attach two InputBindings to a ListViewItem? Can you please post a small code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
<ListView x:Name="ServerListView" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding  MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"   Command="{Binding ElementName=ServerListView, Path=DataContext.ListViewItemDoubleClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"   />
                <MouseBinding  MouseAction="LeftClick"   Command="{Binding ElementName=ServerListView, Path=DataContext.SomeOtherOrSameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"   />
            </ListView.InputBindings>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Dienstname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Servername" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HostName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="IP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IpAddress}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet. But it does not work.
The InputBindings are added to the ListView not to the ListViewItem. So the Click/DoubleClick event is fired when clicking on the ListView. When I click/doubleclick on an item in that ListView nothing appens.

Please see the edit on the original post.